# create matrix lm model with factors

Tags: r, matrix, lm

I'd like to create 100 simulations and create a linear model for each model using a matrix. I used the following code, but got an error. What is the best way to accomplish this?

```
n=15;nsims=100
factor=matrix(as.factor(rep(1:5,3)),n, nsims)
sim=matrix(rnorm(nfactor*nsims,0,1),n,nsims)
> dim(factor)
[1]  15 100
> lm1=lm(sim~factor)
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L,  : 
  replacement has 1500 rows, data has 15
```

Comment: Do you want `lm(c(sim)~c(factor))` ?

Comment: what should the linear model for each simulation look like?  i.e., should it be a fit of a single response vector to a single input variable (i.e. a factor of length 15)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not clear what you want.

Create data:

```
n <- 15; nsims <- 100; nfactor <- 5
f <- matrix(as.factor(rep(1:nfactor,n/nfactor)), n, nsims)
set.seed(101)
sim <- matrix(rnorm(nfactor*nsims,0,1),n,nsims)
```

(In general it's bad practice to name variables with the names of existing functions (`factor`) ...)

```
res <- vector("list", nsims)
for (i in 1:nsims) {
   res[[i]] <- lm(y~x,
                  data=data.frame(y=sim[,i],x=f[,i]))
}
```

A `for` loop may seem clunky, but (as discussed in chapter 4 of the [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)) it's often the clearest way to write your code ...  If you *really* want to do it without a `for` loop, inu the general case where the columns of `f` might differ, you could do

```
res2 <- mapply(function(x,y) lm(y~x),
            split(f,col(f)),split(sim,col(sim)),SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

but I consider that less clear than the `for` loop ...

**update**: I don't know whether it was on purpose or not, but every column of your factor matrix is identical.  Thus you can put the single input variable on the right-hand side of the formula and the matrix response on the left-hand side:

```
all(apply(f[,-1],2,identical,f[,1]))  ## all TRUE
res2 <- lm(sim~f[,1])
```

Comment: I wanted to do it without a for loop. If you take out the as.factor it will run, I'm not sure why as.factor causes the error...

Comment: why do you want to do it without a for loop? (can you clarify that the *results* of my code are what you want?)

Comment: Thanks, Yeah I didn't think to use res2 <- lm(sim~f[,1]). I want get better at r, in the future this is a good solution I think